# Perform regression from CSV file in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am new to R and want to perform a linear regression from the data in a CSV file as follows:

```
    Data = read.csv("ErrorTest.csv",header=T, row.names=NULL)
    regmodel=lm(Error ~ Const, data = Data)
```

However, I am getting the error message:

```
    "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Error' not found"
```

The CSV file is uploaded here: http://www.filedropper.com/errortest

Can someone please explain how to do the regression in R correctly?

Comment: The csv file does not really obey the csv format
`Error;Const`
`-0,44;1`
Can you please explain what the above data means

Comment: @vasanthcullen I saved the CSV file from an Excel sheet with two columns "Error" and "Const". I want to simply regress Error over Const.

Comment: please use `dput(Data)` to include data in your question. Link does not take me to data. Most likely reason is there not being a column called `Error` in `Data`

Comment: @emcor : Cool. The headers are clear now. `-0,44;1` means Error is 44 and Const is 1? Then -0 corresponds to what?

Comment: @RichardTelford : The error is exactly because of that

Comment: Use : `read.csv("ErrorTest.csv",header=T, row.names=NULL ,sep = ";", dec = ",")`. Nevertheless, there is nothing to regress with your `Const` (I assume it is a dummy), since you regress something on 1 which has no variation (if it is a dummy should be in some cases 0).

Comment: @Aneconomist : The data makes sense now :) Thanks

Comment: @Aneconomist Thanks its working now.

Comment: No worries, always happy to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first few lines of your csv file look like this:

```
Error;Const
-0,44;1
-0,58;1
1,10;1
```

The `read.csv`assumes the use of `,` as separator between data and `.` as decimal point character. Meanwhile, judging from your data above, this is not the case. Therefore, you must modify the code used to read in the csv file. After that, you can run the regression model.

```
Data <- read.csv("ErrorTest.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")
regmodel <- lm(Error ~ Const, data = Data)
```

EDIT: An even simpler way of reading in the data is using the built-in function `read.csv2`:

```
read.csv2("Errortest.csv")
```